# Is the Sony Android camera API supported for all Android versions?

Tags: android, sony, sony-camera-api

I'm wondering if the Sony Camera API has parts that are only supported by certain versions of Android.

I have the latest firmware (1.04) on my a6500 and running Android 7 on LineageOS (successor of CyanogenMod) for the Samsung S5 (KLTE version). This is what I get in my Play Memories app:

[image: No Image Settings in Android Play Memories app]

The shutter button works and images download to the phone. But that's it.

Additionally, when I use another app called `DSLRDashboard`, the settings show up and can be changed on the app, but they don't get changed or applied on the camera, and this is in full manual mode on the camera. Other modes don't work either.

What could be causing this? What would need to be added into a 3rd party ROM like LineageOS to get this working?

Really hoping that the official Sony developers that roam this site will be able to chime in.

Comment: No, this question is about Android apps that control Sony DSLRs. There are official Sony apps (PlayMemories App) for Android but there is also a Sony camera API and SDK available for Android developers to make their own apps that can control Sony cameras.

Comment: https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Comment: Ah I see, I was mistaken thinking about using exclusive Camera API on Sony Android phones (which I think apparently it doesn't exist). I removed the previous comment to prevent misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

So, a bit of a snafu on my part.

It's not enough to update just the firmware on the Sony camera. The Remote Control app installed in the camera must also be updated as well, which means hooking the camera up to WiFi and downloading the updates for that app. With that done, all the settings appear in the phone app and can the changed.